# How to push to an embedded list in an array without duplicates using filters and $ in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create an update query for a user for the following use case.

#### Given I'm a user that wants to add an item to a list

#### and I have multiple lists

#### Add the item to the list if it's not already on the list

The same item may appear on multiple lists the user has - but cannot appear on the same list more than once.  This is the query I'm using in mongoose, but the query filters everything out if there is more than one list in the array and I have the filter `'lists.items.id': { '$ne': 'ASIN-B016I2XLBS' }` and there is more than one list.  Should I be querying for `lists.$.items.id`?  Is my insert statement `lists.$.items` not correct when there are multiple items?

```
db.users.findAndModify({ 
  'lists.items.id': { '$ne': 'ASIN-B016I2XLBS' }, 
  'lists._id': ObjectId("585047a43246d621dd96c12e"), 
  username: 'foo' }) [] 
{ '$push': { 'lists.$.items': 
      { prouctName:'bar', id: 'ASIN-B016I2XLBS' } 
    } 
} { new: true, upsert: false, remove: false }
```

sample user

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("585046a535543ff7dc23ae1d"),
    "username" : "foo",
    "lists" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("585046a535543ff7dc23ae1e"),
            "items" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "Regalo My Cot Portable Bed, Royal Blue",
                    "id" : "ASIN-XXXZZZ"
                }, 
                {

                    "name" : "bar"
                    "id" : "ASIN-B016I2XLBS"
                }
            ],
            "name" : "Shopping List"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("585047a43246d621dd96c12e"),
            "items" : [],
            "name" : "Christmas"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If the query matches the array using a negation operator, such as $ne, $not, or $nin, then you cannot use the positional operator to update values from this array. From the docs here https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/positional/

Comment: in this case then, should I use `addToSet` instead of `push` and remove the $ne negation?

Comment: yep the addToSet should do it.

Comment: that would also introduce an edge case where duplicate items may be added if one of the properties are different... e.g. product ids are the same but let's say a description is slightly updated.  Is there a way to avoid that?